# How to search a specific string including a username?

Tags: slack

My company uses automated Slack messages to announce deploys to a `#_production` channel. I want count how many times I have been the deploy lead by doing a search. Specifically, I want to find all slack messages in `#_production` containing the exact string `Deploy lead: @Peter Scriven` where `@Peter Scriven` is My Slack tag.

My issue is when I search **without** quotes i.e. `in:#_production Deploy lead: @Peter Scriven`, I get more results that I want:

[image]

And when I search **with** quotes i.e.: `in:#_production "Deploy lead: @Peter Scriven"`, I get no results:

[image]

Is it possible to search for a specific string containing a username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box functionality to do what you ask.

As a work around, what you can do is perform following search:

```
in:#_production "Deploy lead:" @Peter Scriven
```

i.e. put the regular text in quotes and user without quotes

Comment: This looks like the best way. I sent a message to Slack and they haven't managed to tell me a better way